# you can say so if you must

Tags: discourse-context, auxiliary

I'm wondering if "you can say so if you must" can be used as a concession in the following.

A: I sold everything and moved to Canada with John because I loved him.

B: No, you didn't really love him. You thought you loved him; at that time, you mistook desire for love.

A: OK, you can say so if you must (= if you must say so).

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to "concede" - I'd interpret it as a rather passive-aggressive way of saying "you're wrong" and/or "I don't care about your opinion".

Comment: Maybe the latter. Are you a native speaker of American English or British English?

Comment: Polish, actually :)

Comment: I don't think I'd ever say that. If I were A and trying to shut the conversation down (because B is being quite rude and I didn't want to waste time arguing), I'd probably say "If you say so". Putting 'must' in there doesn't work — it sounds as though they're being made to say it.

Comment: ("If you must" is a phrase, but it would usually be used to refer to an action, rather than something the other person has just said.)

Comment: "You can say that if you *wish/want/like*" sounds more natural to me — you're making it clear it's their idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cited context, ***if you must*** is a slightly "stylised" alternative to the far more common ***if you want***.

Note that as is normal when someone uses ***any*** "less common" variant of a common idiomatic form, we tend to assume there should be at least some *nuance* of difference in meaning.

For me personally, the "idiomatic standard" *You can say that **if you want*** is just a slightly more "colloquially emphatic" alternative to *You **could** say that.* The implication for both of those is normally ***...but I wouldn't use those exact words myself***.

When I see ***must*** rather than ***want*** here, I understand it as being an even ***more*** emphatic turn of phrase. So much so that whereas ***if you want*** simply implies *if that's how you want to phrase it, **that's fine*** (it's up to you), the ***must*** version to me implies something more like ***...if you must insist on annoying me by using words that I wouldn't use myself***.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense, but you need an additional comma to make it clear:

> OK, you can say so, if you must.

Otherwise it could be understood as:

> OK, you can say "so if you must".